# How to do OR filter using DevExtreme React Grid Table with either FilteringState and/or LocalFiltering?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, devextreme

As per the <strike>open</strike> now closed [issue #499](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-reactive/issues/499) under the [devextreme-reactive github repo](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-reactive/), I would like to be able to do some sort of compound filtering under the `Grid`/`TableView` components.

Currently, there are two filtering components with the following respective examples:

[FilteringState](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-reactive/blob/v1.0.0-beta.1/packages/dx-react-demos/src/material-ui/filtering/local-filtering-controlled.jsx)

```es6
import React from 'react';
import {
  FilteringState,
  LocalFiltering,
} from '@devexpress/dx-react-grid';
import {
  Grid,
  TableView,
  TableHeaderRow,
  TableFilterRow,
} from '@devexpress/dx-react-grid-material-ui';

import {
  generateRows,
} from '../../demo-data/generator';

export default class Demo extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      columns: [
        { name: 'name', title: 'Name' },
        { name: 'sex', title: 'Sex' },
        { name: 'city', title: 'City' },
        { name: 'car', title: 'Car' },
      ],
      rows: generateRows({ length: 14 }),
      filters: [{ columnName: 'car', value: 'cruze' }],
    };

    this.changeFilters = filters => this.setState({ filters });
  }
  render() {
    const { rows, columns } = this.state;

    return (
      <Grid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
      >
        <FilteringState
          filters={this.state.filters}
          onFiltersChange={this.changeFilters}
        />
        <LocalFiltering />
        <TableView />
        <TableHeaderRow />
        <TableFilterRow />
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}
```

[LocalFiltering](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-reactive/blob/v1.0.0-beta.1/packages/dx-react-demos/src/material-ui/filtering/custom-filtering-algorithm.jsx)

```es6
import React from 'react';
import {
  FilteringState,
  LocalFiltering,
} from '@devexpress/dx-react-grid';
import {
  Grid,
  TableView,
  TableHeaderRow,
  TableFilterRow,
} from '@devexpress/dx-react-grid-material-ui';

import {
  generateRows,
} from '../../demo-data/generator';

const toLowerCase = value => String(value).toLowerCase();
const filterByCity = (value, filter) => toLowerCase(value).startsWith(toLowerCase(filter.value));
const getColumnPredicate = columnName => (columnName === 'city' ? filterByCity : undefined);

export default class Demo extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      columns: [
        { name: 'name', title: 'Name' },
        { name: 'sex', title: 'Sex' },
        { name: 'city', title: 'City' },
        { name: 'car', title: 'Car' },
      ],
      rows: generateRows({ length: 14 }),
    };
  }
  render() {
    const { rows, columns } = this.state;

    return (
      <Grid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
      >
        <FilteringState defaultFilters={[{ columnName: 'city', value: 'Paris' }]} />
        <LocalFiltering getColumnPredicate={getColumnPredicate} />
        <TableView />
        <TableHeaderRow />
        <TableFilterRow />
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}
```

Both examples are limited by the fact that they can only allow one filter to be applied to each column specified at a time.

In other words, even though I can create multiple filters, each filter can only be applied to one column at a time.

For example let's say I have the data:

```js
[
  {
    name: 'jane',
    lastName: 'doe',
  },
  {
    name: 'davey',
    lastName: 'jones',
  },
  {
    name: 'walter',
    lastName: 'white',
  },
]
```

If I implement a single `SearchBox` component which `onChange()` would send the following filters to the underlying `FilteringState`:

```js
[
  { columnName: 'name', value: 'd' },
  { columnName: 'lastName', value: 'd' },
]
```

Then I would get `No data` since the filters are being applied as **AND** instead of **OR**.

Is there no way to implement a trigger which enables/disables that filters get treated as **OR**?

Or maybe, is there a way to send filters this way?:

```js
[
  { columnNames: ['name', 'lastName'], value: 'd' },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the filtering code base, <strike>the quick answer is **No**</strike> it's not straight forward but it is possible.

**UPDATE:** *one of the library's developer has confirmed there is a way to filter rows. Example appended to end of this answer.*

As I mentioned on the <strike>open</strike> now closed [issue #499](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-reactive/issues/499) under the [devextreme-reactive github repo](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-reactive/) my current work-around is to **pre-filter** the row data before sending it down the `Grid` component.

Based on the `name` / `lastName` example provided in the question, I suggest something akin to the following:

```es6
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import {
  SortingState,
  LocalSorting,
} from '@devexpress/dx-react-grid';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {
  Grid, TableView, TableHeaderRow
} from '@devexpress/dx-react-grid-material-ui';

export default class MySearchableTableView extends Component {
  filterBySearch = ev => {
    const {data} = this.props;
    const searchValue = ev.target.value;
    const filteredData = data.filter(
      row => (toLowerCase(row.name).startsWith(toLowerCase(searchValue)) || toLowerCase(row.lastName).startsWith(toLowerCase(searchValue)))
    );
    this.setState({data: filteredData});
  };

  updateStateFromProps = (props) => {
    this.setState({data: Object.assign({}, props.data)});
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateStateFromProps(this.props);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.updateStateFromProps(nextProps);
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    const { columns } = this.props;

    return [
      <TextField
        key="text-field-component"
        label="Search"
        fullWidth
        onChange={this.filterBySearch}
      />,
      <Grid
        key="grid-component"
        rows={data || []}
        columns={columns || []}
      >
        <TableView />
        <TableHeaderRow />
        <TableFilterRow />
      </Grid>,
    ];
  }
}
```

Hopefully in the near future the **DevExpress** team implements an official way of running compound column filtering.

In the mean-time the previous example should get many use cases up and running while we wait.

### UPDATE

One of the library's developer was kind enough to offer ([on the original issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-reactive/issues/499#issuecomment-346342109)) an example and demo of a way to implement a custom row-based filter:

First, create a custom filter row with a single filter editor. Next, use the onChange event handler to create a custom filter:

```es6
<TableFilterRow
  filterRowTemplate={() => (<TableRow>
      <TableCell>
        <Input
          onChange={(e) => {
            this.setState({ filters: [
              {
                columnName: 'custom',
                value: e.target.value
              }
            ]});
          }}
        />
      </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  )}
/>
```

Then, use this filter within a column predicate:

```es6
<LocalFiltering
  getColumnPredicate={() => (value, filter, row) => (
    row.firstFieldName.indexOf(filter.value) > -1
    ||
    row.secondFieldName.indexOf(filter.value) > -1
  )}
/>
```

At a first glance it seems to me this would cause the row filter to be run multiple times as it is run per row's column under `getColumnPredicate`.

Then again, `devextreme-reactive` devs [have confirmed](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-reactive/issues/499#issuecomment-346356584):

*It depends on the filter count, not on the column count. Each filter will be applied for each row.*